# Why does \jobname give asterisks/stars instead of spaces, and how do I fix this?

Tags: miktex, shell-escape, filesystem-access, jobname

When I LaTeX a file named `test 1.tex` with the code `\edef\temp{\jobname.txt}\show\temp`, I get

```
> \temp=macro:
->test*1.txt.
```

This seems to work fine with LaTeX's internal commands, but if I then mix this with `\write18`, it fails.
For example, something like

```
\newwrite\tempwrite
\immediate\openout\tempwrite\temp\relax
\immediate\write\tempwrite{test}
\immediate\closeout\tempwrite
\immediate\write18{rm "\temp"}
```

How can I get a version of `\jobname` that actually uses spaces instead of the asterisks?  (Can I do something fancy with catcodes to make `\write18` transform asterisks into spaces?)

Comment: Easy solution: Do not use spaces in filenames with (La)TeX! Never!

Comment: Which LaTeX distribution in which version and which executable are you using on which OS? It works fine for me (no `*`s) with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010) under Ubuntu Linux. A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that causes the `*`s to appear would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps the `*` has catcode 10?? Try `\edef\temp{\jobname}\def\showr#1{\show#1\showr}\expandafter\showr\temp{.\show}`.

Comment: I was using MiKTeX 2.9 under Windows 7.  My laptop recently died, so I'll give the results of `\edef\temp{\jobname}\def\showr#1{\show#1\showr}\expandafter\showr\temp{.\show}` the next time I have access to a windows machine with LaTeX.

Comment: Using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9) on windows 7, the `\showr` sequence just shows me the name of the file, with *s instead of spaces (it doesn't say, e.g., "the letter a").

I tried `echo "\edef\temp{\jobname}\def\showr#1{\message{\detokenize{#1}}\showthe\catcode\`#1\showr}\expandafter\showr\temp{.\show}" > "temp a1a_.tex" && latex "temp a1a_.tex"` and it gave me the characters `temp*a1a_` with catcodes 11,11,11,11,12,11,12,11,8.

Comment: @Jason: Is this still an issue? I can't replicate it with TeXLive under Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behaviour is MiKTeX-specific: TeX Live on Windows behaves in the same way as on other platforms, and quotes the file name.

What you can do is convert the `*` characters into spaces. Something like

```
\edef\Jobname{\jobname}
\catcode`\*=\active
\def*{ }
\edef\Jobname{"\detokenize\expandafter{\scantokens\expandafter{\Jobname\noexpand}"}}
\edef\Jobname{\detokenize\expandafter{\Jobname}}
\catcode`\*=12 %
\show\Jobname
```

(using e-TeX) will do the task cleanly. Of course, that will only work if there are no `*` characters in the file name. (There should not be, but it is *possible* to end up with this type of awkward file name!)

Comment: One could use a classical TeX loop to remove the `*` here: I've simply taken a 'short cut' as one is available!

Comment: MiKTeX has recently been updated to follow the TeX Live approach on this: names with spaces are now quoted rather than using `*` chars.