# inputenc -w- \scantokens \expandafter

Tags: pdftex, miktex, external-files, input-encodings

Sorry to bother everyone again - this is a followup question to my earlier question:

[Can openout handle a filename with spaces?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226710/can-openout-handle-a-filename-with-spaces)

(I suppose I can combine this with the earlier question, but this seems to be a "gotcha" of the original question.)
While I have a solution there, it breaks when using filenames with umlauts *and* when using either latin1/utf8 input encodings. The MWE gets an additional line (to break it):

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

The errors are different for each case.
Since it works *without* the inputenc package, I'm very tempted to say, "just remove this line and see what happens."

I looked around and found the following question (which seemed most pertinant):

[fontenc vs inputenc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc)

The discussion there seems to say that inputenc will change the umlaut character to a tex macro.
So ö becomes \"o etc.

My question is, does this expansion break the code that handles the asterisk/space replacement below?
If so, then do I need to expand/replace the \scantokens macro with a loop that checks for this extra condition? yuck!

MWE:

```
% "test öffnen.tex"
% Variations in run command to illustrate a more specific requirement ...
% Without {inputenc}
% Works: >h:\MikTeX\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\pdflatex "test öffnen.tex"
% Works: >h:\MikTeX\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\pdflatex "-job-name=test oeffnen" "test öffnen.tex"
% Works: >h:\MikTeX\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\pdflatex "-job-name=test öffnen" "test öffnen.tex"
% BROKEN with \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
% BROKEN with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%        >h:\MikTeX\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\pdflatex "-job-name=test öffnen" "test öffnen.tex"
% Same run-command as above, different package
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%%% jobname=test*Ã¶ffnen
%%% ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
%%% \font@name ->
%%%              \T1/cmr/m/n/10 
%%% l.27 ...scantokens\expandafter{\JobnameX\noexpand}
%%%                                                   }
%%% If you really absolutely need more capacity,
%%% you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%% produces error on console: pdflatex: Windows API error 1113: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.
\typeout{jobname=\jobname}
% Convert jobname
\edef\JobnameX{\jobname}
\catcode`\*=\active
\def*{ }
\edef\JobnameX{\scantokens\expandafter{\JobnameX\noexpand}}
\catcode`\*=12 %
\newcommand{\TestFilename}{\JobnameX .ips}
\typeout{TestFilename=\TestFilename}
%%%
%%%
\begin{document} 
%%% Write stuff to output - then read it back into a pdfobj
\newwrite\MyFilehandle
\immediate\openout\MyFilehandle="\TestFilename"
\typeout{Test writing stuff to output file=\TestFilename}
\immediate\write\MyFilehandle{Test writing stuff to output file=\TestFilename}
\immediate\closeout\MyFilehandle
\immediate\pdfobj file {\TestFilename} %%% Just to show a snapshot of the entire process.
%%%   FYI - we embed papertray/bursting/external page requirement commands for postprocessing
%%%   (actually written as a 'pagepiece' dictionary)
%%%
%%% Write some text to create a pdf
Write some text into the pdf.
\end{document}
\endinput
```

The error when using latin1 says I should expand TeXs stack. Which I guess I could do - only I'm not convinced that that is the problem. It seems more like a symptom.

Comment: Note that MiKTeX has recently been updated w.r.t. spaces in names: it no longer uses `*` chars but now uses the same quoting approach as TeX Live does.

Comment: Thanks for the "heads up" - I'll definately take a look at it. Do you have an idea what it's doing with umlauts in command line parameter strings?

Comment: If you don't use inputenc you won't be able to use umlauts and accented chars in your document, you will have to write \"a instead of ä. *If* you use inputenc, you should use the option that tells the truth about the encoding of your document: Type an "ä" and then use the option where the output is correct. Imho you shouldn't use scantokens on the jobname. If you need to replace spaces better do a string replacement which doesn't change the other catcodes in the name.

Comment: @JosephWright - thanks - I finally got around to looking at the recent update to MikTeX. 
Oddly enough, if an umlaut is in the file Name I get the interesting output of (first few lines):
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.7.30)  30 JUL 2015 17:14
entering extended mode
**mwe*Ã¤*test.tex

("C:\ . . .\_test_miktex29\20150728\stack_exchange\mwe 
Ã¤ test.tex"       
- There is a funny Symbol following the umlaut, (which gets capitalized) does the update handle latin chars in the file name?

Comment: @JosephWright - which module(s) got updated? (and what are you referring to?) On further tests I've now noticed that pdflatex in the newer MikTeX behaves the same as the older version - blanks get replaced with asterisks. Were you referring to a different Version of pdflatex?(i.e. Version 3.0?)